# Adding ScrollPane to BoxLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jscrollpane

IN MY PROGRAM, 
I have a button when pressed, adds a new JPanel to a JPanel with BOXLAYOUT. Since when I add the JPanel it adds it to the bottom of the previous one. BUT THERE IS NO SCROLL BAR.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class tes{


public static void main(String[] args) {


        JFrame newL = new JFrame();
        newL.setTitle("New Level Files");
        //newL.setLayout(new BoxLayout());
        //t.setSize(500,600);
            //newL.pack();
            newL.setVisible(true);
            newL.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


            JPanel listPane = new JPanel();
            listPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(listPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(listPane,   ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));

            newL.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


            JPanel levelP = new JPanel();
            levelP.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            levelP.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints l = new GridBagConstraints();
            l.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,5);







            JButton okForFileEdit = new JButton("Edit this File");

            l.gridx = 1;
            l.gridy = 6;
            levelP.add(okForFileEdit, l);





            okForFileEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent n){

                    JPanel createInPanel = new JPanel();
                    createInPanel.setSize(200,200);
                    createInPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    createInPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


                    listPane.add(createInPanel);


                    JLabel yout = new JLabel("YEah this is a long sentence to see the placement");
                    createInPanel.add(yout);

                    listPane.revalidate();
                    listPane.repaint();

                    newL.revalidate();

                }});

            listPane.add(levelP);
            listPane.revalidate();
           listPane.repaint();
            newL.add(listPane);


            newL.pack();


    }
```

** I added a SIMPLIFIED VERSION OF THE PROGRAM THAT DOESN'T MAKE THE SCROLLBAR
Hope this makes more sense. Thanks for the help in advance :);

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. We can't copy/paste/compile/test the code you posted.

Comment: Yes I have done so now

Comment: This will allow you to copy this prgram and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a button when pressed, adds a new JPanel to a JPanel with BOXLAYOUT.

When you dynamically add components to a panel the basic logic need in your ActionListener is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

You need to invoke the revalidate method to invoke the layout manager of the panel so the preferred size can be recalculated.

Edit:

```
newL.add(listPane);
```

You don't need the above statement. A Swing component can only have a single parent. That statement removed the panel from the scroll pane so you don't see the scroll bars.

```
newL.revalidate();
```

You don't need that statement. As I said in my answer you only need to revalidate() the panel that you changed.

Also you don't need all the statements below:

```
        listPane.add(levelP);
        listPane.revalidate();
       listPane.repaint();
        newL.add(listPane);
```

That is the layout manager is invoked when you pack the frame of make the frame visible. Your code should be:

```
newl.pack();
newl.setVisible(true);
```

That is you should only make the frame visible AFTER adding all the components to the frame.

Comment: i already did this in the action, I POSTED THE PIC ^^^ . Doesn't bring up the scrollbar even though the panel has been added (And is under the first panel but can't be seen)